# woocommerce_checkout_order_processed hook executing function twice

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have attached a function to the `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` hook:

```
//check if woocommerce is acive
if (in_array('woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters('active_plugins', get_option('active_plugins')))) {
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wc_on_place_order');
}
```

The `wc_on_place_order` function is to be executed after the user clicks on the <kbd>PLACE ORDER</kbd> button. However, it's so odd that the function is executed twice.

My `wc_on_place_order` function calls an external api written in C#:

```
function wc_on_place_order( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb;

    // get order object and order details
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id ); 
    
    // get product details
    $items = $order->get_items();
    //return $items;
    
    $products = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        array_push($products, 
            array('userid' => $order->user_id, 'descr' => $item['name'], 'amt' => (float)$item['line_total'])
        );
    }

    //passing $products to external api using `curl_exec`
    . . . .

    //on successful call, the page should be showing an `alert`, however, it does not
    // the handle response    
    if (strpos($response,'ERROR') !== false) {
            print_r($response);
    } else {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert($response)</script>";
    }
}
```

After debugging on C# API, I noticed that it the service is being called twice, thus, the checkout is being saved twice to the API database.

Is there something wrong with the `wc_on_place_order` function or is `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` called twice when clicking the <kbd>PLACE ORDER</kbd>?

Interestingly, adding `return $items` after `$items = $order->get_items()` somehow, the C# api was only called once:

```
// get product details
$items = $order->get_items();
return $items; //this line
```

Why is that so?

One more question I would like to ask, is `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` the right hook I should use? I have been searching the web for the correct hook to use and it seems that `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` is used in the most post. I can't use the `woocommerce_thankyou` hook as it is also calling the API if I refresh the page.

Any idea will be really appreciated.

**EDIT:**

> I used `woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` hook which fires after pre-validations on checkout. I can't remember though why `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` is being fired twice but I just changed some kind of settings in `WooCommerce` options page. I can't remember which.

### Useful Links from the Comments:

- [Visual Representation of the WooCommerce hooks](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/)
- [WordPress Action References](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference)

Answer (score 5):

I always use the hook `woocommerce_payment_complete`  This will fire as the name suggests after the order has been paid.

```
function order_payment_complete( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    /* Insert your code */
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'order_payment_complete' );
```

Comment: this works but ill be looking for a better hook. seems i can't stop woocommerce from redirecting to the "thank you" page from this hook

Comment: You can redirect the user to a different page after checkout, would that solve your issue?

Comment: I would like to remain to the current page. See, I am calling an external api to check if the current user has a balance on that endpoint and then, if the user has no balance, i would like to show an error message or something.

Comment: Then you're using the wrong hooks. Try the action woocommerce_checkout_process where you can create an error via wc_add_notice() function which will inform the user of zero balance.

Comment: @andrew, where is the best place to learn about the order of hooks here? Is there somebody sort of flow chart of hooks and when they are called?

Comment: @Madivad i don't know of any resources. I just view the source code if I want to know the order of actions or want to find an appropriate action or filter to use.  WordPress has an action list that shows the order but I have never seen one for WooCommerce https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSchultz, I usually get overwhelmed by the source code, so much happening, but I'm certainaly getting a better understanding by doing it. Although I did find a good visual reference for a lot of the woocommerce stuff (I'm just posting this for general info, this is just one example, this guy has posted oodles of examples like this, just click the `visual hook series` link in the intro. for me this is perfect: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-visual-hook-guide-archiveshopcat-page/ )